# Gulp Vinyl-FTP timing out

Tags: ftp, gulp, vinyl-ftp

I am learning Gulp and want to try to put my .css files on a remote server. I have installed Vinyl FTP for this. My Gulp file is as such:

Whenever I run the ftp command I get a message `ERROR Error: Timeout while connecting to server`.

My gulpfile.js file is as such:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require( 'gulp-util' );  
var ftp = require( 'vinyl-ftp' );

/** FTP Configuration **/
var user = 'myusername';  
var password = 'password';  
var host = '123.456.789.100'; //I have also tried 'ftp.mysite.com'
var port = 21;  
var localFilesGlob = ['css/*.css'];  
var remoteFolder = '/css'

// helper function to build an FTP connection based on our configuration
function getFtpConnection() {  
    return ftp.create({
        host: host,
        port: port,
        user: user,
        password: password,
        parallel: 5,
        log: gutil.log
    });
}

gulp.task('ftp-deploy', function() {
    var conn = getFtpConnection();
    console.log(conn); //<--this seems to have the correct info
    return gulp.src(localFilesGlob, { base: '.', buffer: false })
        .pipe( conn.newer( remoteFolder ) ) // only upload newer files 
        .pipe( conn.dest( remoteFolder ) )
    ;
});
```

Obviously, I've checked out the user name and password. I can connect to the server fine with my FTP client.

I've also tried swapping out 'base' with 'cwd'.

I am running this in Mac Terminal, if that matters.

Would anyone know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me.  My guess would be an issue with `passive/active` ftp mode.  It is usually the reason with ftps.

What did you try with your FTP client (did you have active or passive mode?).

Apparently `vinyl-ftp` does not support it yet as it is on the [TODO list](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp/blob/67680c22caaa8621969d6a23c84266eb779b8fdb/TODO).

I'm afraid there is [no workaround](https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp/issues/10) for the moment.